# if someone deletes my app withh the number of downloadds from google play decrease?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

if someone deletes my app withh the number of downloadds from google play decrease ?
Today I saw that number of downloads in my app decreased to 100. But yesterday was 336 in google ads and in google console 218 but in google play i saw only 100. Does any body have the same problem? What is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When some uninstalls an app the number decreases in your analytics. When you the 100 million downloads on the app page for example, that basically says it's been downloaded that many times. That is not the current count.

The analytics shows you the total downloads, active (daily) users, inactive users and uninstalled. All of those numbers mean different things.

So in your case if your looking at the analytics you will see a wide range of numbers. The main one you need to focus on is the current (daily) active users.

With the ads it's a whole different ball game. If you have 100 downloads then only half of them get on daily, then the ad portion only accounts for active users not inactive users. So you may have one day 40 ad increase and another day 50 ad decrease. Those numbers on the ads is by who opened your app not by how many downloaded the app.

So your daily active users should be close to your daily ad number. If you have 40 active users then your ad should be close to 40.

This also depends on which ad company you are using.. Google admob uses at least 10 different numbers but in those analytics there will be a daily active user.

So if you revenue is from ads, your daily users make your ad revenue. So your numbers is based on your active users, with inactive or uninstalled will not be recognized in the ads because they are not seeing ads.